# Cython - calculating an array of distances between 2D coordinates

Tags: python, cython

I have a function that use a generator to loop over large 2D python lists of float coordinates in order to create flat lists of integers that represent the distance between coordinates.

```
point_input = {"x": -8081441.0, "y": 5685214.0}
output = [-8081441, 5685214]

polyline_input = {"paths" : [[-8081441.0, 5685214.0], [-8081446.0, 5685216.0], [-8081442.0, 5685219.0], [-8081440.0, 5685211.0], [-8081441.0, 5685214.0]]}
output = [[-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]]

polygon_input = {"rings" : [[-8081441.0, 5685214.0], [-8081446.0, 5685216.0], [-8081442.0, 5685219.0], [-8081440.0, 5685211.0], [-8081441.0, 5685214.0]]}
output = [[-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]]
```

**pure python:**

```
def geometry_to_distance(geometry, geometry_type):
    def calculate_distance(coords):
        iterator = iter(coords)
        previous_x, previous_y = iterator.next()
        yield int(previous_x)
        yield int(previous_y)
        for current_x, current_y in iterator:
            yield int(previous_x - current_x)
            yield int(previous_y - current_y)
            previous_x, previous_y = current_x, current_y

    if geometry_type == "POINT":
        distance_array = [int(geometry["x"]), int(geometry["y"])]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYLINE":
        distance_array = [list(calculate_distance(path)) for path in geometry["paths"]]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYGON":
        distance_array = [list(calculate_distance(ring)) for ring in geometry["rings"]]
    else:
        raise Exception("{} geometry type not supported".format(geometry_type))

    return distance_array
```

For speed performance, I want to use cython implementation of the same function. I am using type declaration for integer variables in the `calculate_distance` function.

**cython implementation:**

```
def geometry_to_distance(geometry, geometry_type):
    def calculate_distance(coords):
        cdef int previous_x, previous_y, current_x, current_y
        iterator = iter(coords)
        previous_x, previous_y = iterator.next()
        yield previous_x
        yield previous_y
        for current_x, current_y in iterator:
            yield previous_x - current_x
            yield previous_y - current_y
            previous_x, previous_y = current_x, current_y 

    if geometry_type == "POINT":
        distance_array = [geometry["x"], geometry["y"]]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYLINE":
        distance_array = [list(calculate_distance(path)) for path in geometry["paths"]]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYGON":
        distance_array = [list(calculate_distance(ring)) for ring in geometry["rings"]]
    else:
        raise Exception("{} geometry type not supported".format(geometry_type))

    return distance_array
```

**here a script that can be used to benchmark the function:**

```
import time
from functools import wraps
import numpy as np
import geometry_converter as gc

def timethis(func):
    '''Decorator that reports the execution time.'''
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(func.__name__, end-start)
        return result
    return wrapper


def prepare_data(featCount, size):
    ''' Create arrays of polygon geometry (see polygon_input above)'''
    input = []
    for i in xrange(0, featCount):
        polygon = {"rings" : []}
        #random x,y coordinates inside a quadrant of the world bounding box in a spherical mercator (epsg:3857) projection
        ys = np.random.uniform(-20037507.0,0,size).tolist()
        xs = np.random.uniform(0,20037507.0,size).tolist()
        polygon["rings"].append(zip(xs,ys))
        input.append(polygon)
    return input

@timethis
def process_data(data):
    output = [gc.esriJson_to_CV(x, "POLYGON") for x in data]
    return output

data = prepare_data(100, 100000)
process_data(data)
```

Is there improvements that could increase performance in the cython implementation? maybe by using 2D cython arrays or carrays?

Comment: Why not just use `numpy.diff` to take the 1st difference of the X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Because it appears that creating numpy.array from the huge 2D python lists is too slow.

Comment: You'd have the same problem going to cython or c arrays as well. Lists are not stored in contiguous memory while (homogenous) numpy, cython, and c arrays are. So the conversion will take some time regardless of these approaches. I'm surprised `numpy.diff` isn't faster than the cython implementation considering the use of generators and lists.

Comment: you can see [a numpy function that do the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40893149/1914034), but even if its faster to calculate the distance, the conversion to numpy array make it a little bit slower overall

Comment: Then I would rule out getting much more of a benefit from cython with lists. You could try using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) which now supports lists in `nopython` mode, but if you can get the output as a numpy array from arcpy that would be ideal.

Comment: @pbreach thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, arcpy cannot return polygon and polyline geometry as numpy array. In fact, the python list are created from json.loads(). Maybe I should use a cython json parser that would load the json into c arrays such [cyjson](https://github.com/mitghi/cyjson)

Comment: You could try `pandas`? It has  fast io and would probably be much faster than using the json module

Answer (score 1):

The Python, rewritten without the generator, is

```
In [362]: polyline_input = {"paths" : [[-8081441.0, 5685214.0], [-8081446.0, 568
     ...: 5216.0], [-8081442.0, 5685219.0], [-8081440.0, 5685211.0], [-8081441.0
     ...: , 5685214.0]]}
In [363]: output=polyline_input['paths'][0][:] # copy
In [364]: i0,j0 = output
     ...: for i,j in polyline_input['paths'][1:]:
     ...:     output.extend([i0-i, j0-j][:])
     ...:     i0,j0 = i,j
     ...:     
In [365]: output
Out[365]: [-8081441.0, 5685214.0, 5.0, -2.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, 8.0, 1.0, -3.0]
```

I'm just thinking though alternative ways of expressing the calculation.  I could have used `append` to a list of pairs instead of the flat list.

An array equivalent:

```
In [375]: arr=np.array(polyline_input['paths'])
In [376]: arr[1:,:]=arr[:-1,:]-arr[1:,:]
In [377]: arr.ravel().tolist()
Out[377]: [-8081441.0, 5685214.0, 5.0, -2.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, 8.0, 1.0, -3.0]
```

Ignoring the cost of converting a list to array, that looks like an efficient numpy operation.  To improve on it in cython I expect you'd have to convert the array to memoryview, and iterate `c` style over pairs of values.

I forget why you are switching to this distance format.  Are you trying to save some file space?  Or speed up some downstream calculation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes the aim is to get a lightweight representation of the geometry to increase speed of sharing on network